# atualizar vários registros com checkbox php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, sql-update

Preciso de atualizar uma tabela mysql com dados vindos de um/dois checkbox onde checked é 2 e unchecked é 1.

Acontece que se checar o id6 da col1 ele vai atualizar o id4.

O que estará errado?

A minha tabela mysql está assim:

```
id col1 col2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    2    1
4    1    2
5    1    2
6    1    2
7    1    2
```

Da forma como montei a atualização:

Utilizo um form conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
```

os meus checkbox mais o id:

```
<input name="id[]" id="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" /> 

<input name="col1[]" type="checkbox" id="col1[]" value="2" <?php if($row['col1']==2) echo 'checked="checked"';?> />

<input name="col2[]" type="checkbox" id="col2[]" value="2" <?php if($row['col2']==2) echo 'checked="checked"';?> />
```

O meu código na própria página:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)){
        //-->
        $count = count($_POST['id']); 
        $i = 0; 
        //-->
        while ($i < $count) { 
            $id = $_POST['id'][$i]; 
            $col1= $_POST['col1'][$i]; 

            //-->
            $query = "UPDATE table SET col1= '$col1' WHERE id = '$id'";
            mysqli_query($con,$query);
            //-->
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index.php">';
            ++$i; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Nao ta atualizando so o primeiro registo por causa do meta refresh? Tenta colocá-lo após do while

Comment: Dica: Eu converto para json os checkbox e salvo no banco como string, fica mais fácil de recuperar e adicionar mais opções sem precisar alterar o banco

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, tente dessa forma

```
<script>
   function atualizar(id){
      var ck = document.getElementById(id).checked; //verifica se o checkbox estamarcado
      if(ck){ // se estiver marcado
         $("#res").load("atualizar.php", {id:id, valor:2}); //passa o id e o novo valor para a pagina de atualização
      }
      else{ //caso não esteja marcado
         $("#res").load("atualizar.php", {id:id, valor:1}); //passa o id e o outro valor para a pagina de atualização
      }
   }
</script>
```

Basta incluir o evento `onchange` no input e passar o id como parametro, o script vai verificar se esta marcando ou desmarcando o checkbox, e para cada uma das duas opções ele vai passar pra pagina de atualização um novo valor e o id que deve ser atualizado no bd.
A claro crie uma `div` com o id res para conter a pagina de atualização!